Consecutive open compound words - hyphenate?
How would you list consecutive open compound words?
I understand the usage of suspended hyphens in hyphenated, and closed compound words, like ground-, water-, and air-based or over- and underfed cats (from here).
But I haven't been able to find similar examples for open compound words.
An example is listing types of beans:

This dish is going to need adzuki beans, green beans, black beans, and
cannellini beans.

Can this be written as:

This dish is going to need adzuki-, green-, black-, and cannellini
beans.

..or something similar?
Also, I understand that in the case of something as commonly known as beans, it could probably be written as:

This dish is going to need adzuki, green, black, and cannellini beans.

and everybody would understand the meaning behind it. But in my actual use case, this would be very ambiguous, since it concerns lesser known compound words; "data models, data templates, data dictionaries, data formats, and data standards". A "data dictionary" and a "dictionary" have different meanings, so the connection to the common prefix should be clear.
I generally use British English in my writing.
Thanks in advance!

I would use this This dish is going to need adzuki, green, black, and cannellini beans. I would only hyphenate like you showed if each one separately uses (or could use) a hyphen, and final one is complete in form, this:  I am not upper-, middle-, or lower-class.

I'm not fond of "...going to need adzuki, green, black," etc. It has the potential to be confusing. Adzuki is a type of bean, but if the list started with "green" or "black," the reader might be well into the list before they realized what it was a list of. I would simply repeat "beans" all those times and have a perfectly clear conscience about it. Efficiency that reduces clarity is not a goal.

The difference between suspended hyphen lists and compound word lists is that the hyphens also serve to indicate that we haven't yet reached the end of the list, where there will be a category word to link them. So the pattern is understood from the start of the list. With compound nouns, omitting the category word means there's no clue that an underlying theme will link the list words. The potential for ambiguity is thus greater.

Just posted an answer. I would be happy to make more suggestions, but I would need an example of the sentence or paragraph you are trying to write

@PeterKirkpatrick would you in that case say it's acceptable to use hyphens even though the compound words themselves are open? Or would you repeat the category word, as Andy Bonner suggests? My actual sentence is: "There, considerations around data models, -templates, -dictionaries, -formats, and -standards are exceedingly pertinent."

First, I would not put hyphens in that sentence. See Michael Harvey's comment above. His good example of upper-class, etc, works; but only because it's a list of hyphenated words already. Second, in that exact sentence I would repeat data (without hyphens). Third, I would try really hard to redesign the whole sentence. There, considerations around the tools of data analysis, such as models, templates, dictionaries, formats, and standards, are exceedingly pertinent.

I googled for technical documentation on the web for "data lake database data warehouse", because I know these are compared and can be found in lots of writings, and found a couple where all the time they write out all of them, never simplify, three of them as examples:

What is a Data Lake? (MS Azure)
Database vs. Data lake vs. Data warehouse: What's the difference? (Redpanda)
What’s the Difference Between a Data Warehouse, Data Lake, and Data Mart? (AWS)

Based on this I would say you should write out "data" all the time, however annoying it is.

In the actual case, I'd try to rephrase, perhaps as "models, templates, dictionaries, formats, and standards for data".  Or perhaps a more radical change, splitting up the information into several sentences.
If that's impossible, and you are writing some kind of technical report, a lack of ambiguity is preferred over elegant prose.  If that is the case,  go for the inelegant but correct: "data models, data templates, data dictionaries, data formats, and data standards"
In the beans example, the hyphens might help a little. They aren't essential and "adzuki, green, black, and cannellini beans" is quite understandable too.

The rephrasing can't be done, as all of those enumerated are IT phrases for specific things, e.g. a data dictionary is a special tool compared to a general dictionary, the latter being also for data storage (I mean remaining in the IT topic and not even considering meanings outside of it).

It sounds like you are writing some kind of technical report.  In such a report, a lack of ambiguity is preferred over elegant prose.  If that is the case,  go for the inelegant but correct : "data models, data templates, data dictionaries, data formats, and data standards"

@JamesK Yup, thanks, I ended up redesigning the sentence to make it sound less awkward, but generally sticking to writing out "data" every time to limit ambiguity.

Context is King
In a technical context, I would entirely omit the word "data." While it is true that most people in most situations think of a dictionary as a paper book containing definitions of words, no one will make that mistake if you are writing an article about C#, Python, or Javascript. With respect to James K, I would not say "dictionaries for data," just as I would never say "beans of cannellini."

Thanks for your answer. You're right, the context is important. In my situation, however, the tricky thing is that the compound words, e.g. data dictionary each have a specific meaning, separate from the words on their own. The text is on software architecture related topics, thus is pretty close to programming and "dictionary" by itself could very well be interpreted as both a language dictionary or a programming data type, neither of which is the correct one...
I would definitely also not say "dictionaries for data" bc of the above-mentioned.

I'm not sure if it's going to make it clearer, but the text is:
"One such project is XX which centres around an open material- and building passport. There, considerations around data models, data templates, data dictionaries, data formats, and data standards are exceedingly pertinent."
I might just have to rewrite this altogether or write this as:
"There, considerations around data models, templates, dictionaries, formats, and standards are exceedingly pertinent."
and hope it's understandable enough.

I've had a go above at an alternative sentence to give you some ideas. For this paragraph, don't hyphenate material unless you would hyphenate it in isolation (material-passport?)

@martina I think your rewritten sentence is perfectly understandable in any software context- go with that! Also, as Peter says, you don't need to hyphenate words like material, even if you are adding another descriptor before passport. I would thus hyphenate My brother- and sister-in-law because brother-in-law and sister-in-law are hyphenated on their own

@PeterKirkpatrick you're right, material and building passport (material passport and building passport) is exactly the same case as with the "data" words. I ended up redesigning the whole paragraph to try to make it sound less awkward
