How would write these two open compound nouns consecutively?
I saw there's already a post addressing this issue and the best answer there was to repeat the group noun, but is there no other option?
In my case, I'd need to write "customer and market orientation" as in customer orientation and market orientation. Will people reading this immediately understand that "customer" is just the first half or are they likely to trip over it?

It's going to depend on the context - if "customer" on its own would fit there, then it's more of a problem but if "customer" wouldn't make sense then you're OK. Note that customer is a countable noun and orientation might be a mass noun. But without more information, this seems a duplicate.

It's a bad jargony phrase to begin with.  Its meaning is not clear. The best way to rewrite it is to make your meaning clearer.  What is customer orientation?   What is market orientation?

I see what you mean but unfortunately I can't change it - it's a work thing that I have no control over. But it generally got me thinking what the convention was to write consecutive open compound nouns that share the same group noun.

There's no general rule, it depends on whether it makes sense to consider "customer and market" as a single concept. "peanut butter and jelly sandwich" is not a "peanut butter sandwich and jelly sandwich" because we know that PB and J go together.

Can you please link to the post addressing this already?  This is probably a duplicate of that one.  The best solution is probably to repeat the word,

You could say the orientation of the customer and of the market if they are distinct unrelated things; but if they are oriented to each other in a relationship, such as supply-and-demand, you could say the customer-market orientation or the orientation of customer and market

@JamesK This is the post:
https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/355305/consecutive-open-compound-words-hyphenate
